# Unable to get property 'classList' of undefined or null reference - on first MouseClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm just trying to Code a svg Editor and ther of Course I have some Events.

My actual Question belongs to changing the class-list ov a svg-element, when clicking on it, to mark it as selected, with some css-styles.

So every Symbol, which is loaded out of a database gets the class draggable and preview and an eventlistener, which fires on mouseclick.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
...some code...

addSymbolMouseEvents(document.getElementsByClassName('draggable'));
}

function addSymbolMouseEvents(svgSymbols) {
    for (var i = 0; i < svgSymbols.length; i++) {
        svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', symbolMouseEnter);
        svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('mouseover', symbolMouseOver);
        svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('mouseout', symbolMouseOut);
        svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('click', symbolClick);
        svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('dblclick', symbolDblClick);
        svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', symbolRightClick);
    }
    return svgSymbols;
}
```

So far it works, click is fired.
Now if one clicks on an element, the element should get the class selected and the class preview should be removed, so stroke-width is changed by class-style:

```js
function symbolClick(evt) {
    //deselect all symbols
    var selectableSymbols = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectableSymbols.length; i++) {
        selectableSymbols[i].classList.remove("selected");
        selectableSymbols[i].classList.add("preview");
    }

    //select the firing symbol
    this.classList.add("selected");
    this.classList.remove("preview");
}
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    svg {
        border: 1px dotted #808080;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background: #fafafa;
    }

    .selected {
        stroke-width: 1;
        opacity: 1;
        stroke: #0026ff
    }

    .draggable {
        cursor: grab;
        /*stroke-width: 0.8;
        stroke: #000000;
        opacity: 0.8;*/
    }

    .preview {
        cursor: grab;
        stroke-width: 0.8;
        stroke: #000000;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .mouseovereffect {
        opacity: 1;
        stroke-width: 1;
    }

</style>
```

I don't know why, but I only get it run on second click.
On first Click, every preview style is deleted and on second click, the selected style is set.
Is there an easier way to highlight the selected Symbols?

Comment: The markup is missing from the stacksnippet

Comment: `this` in symbolClick() refers to window.

Answer (score 0):

No,

> this

refers to the symbol, which fired the event, I think.

By now I changed the order of the css-styles, so I don't have to remove the preview-class.
Actually it's working like this:

```js
//remove al selected-classes
var selectableSymbols = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectableSymbols.length; i++) {
        selectableSymbols[i].classList.remove("selected");
    }
//add new selected
this.classList.add("selected");
```